# Make my pi a music and notification centre

Tags: wireless, audio

I was thinking about making my RPi like a music hub, that I can control from my phone. So say I'm at home and want to paly same music, I just get my phone out and select the song I want.
I was thinking about using RaspBMC an Yatse but I eventually want it to be a notification centre so when a mail arrives to me it says me I've got a mail through the speakers.
Does someone know any program/way to do this?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Give a try for logitech media server. Please read my answer. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19685/transmit-music-to-multiple-iphones/19687#19687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspbmc is the best approach. You can use as a Music/Video hub. There are many addons to use on demand content as well. You can control with your phone using the official XBMC app.

There is a email addon, but I never use it. Google it and see if fits in your needs.

A nice feature is this notification that you spoke, if you receive a call or message, a notification will pop up in your TV.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush and didn't remember to ask the question. It is if someone knows any program/way that can do what I am trying to do. Edited. Thanks for remembering. :)

Comment: What happened? Why I received a -1?

Comment: It wasn't me. But anyway I've voted you're answer as accepted. I can't vote, I need 15 reputation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But if I want to make it for example to notice me when  I get a new WhatsApp, could I use for example EventGhost to do that?

Comment: Oh man, you really wants to concentrate everything in your Rpi. No, eventghost doesn't do this, but you can make a extension if you want. Search for Yowsup.

Comment: Yuwsup seems more ore less what I want but it's no longer available on the GitHub. What I meant is that from my mobile phone, with tasker, I send a message to eventghost. And yes I want to concentrate everything in my raspberry pi because I think it's a great way of learning new things.