# Transmit music to multiple iPhones

Tags: wireless, data-transfer

I'm interested in getting a group of iPhones to receive a wireless signal to play music from another source in the same room, essentially acting as a radio receiver.

Originally I imagined that this could be done by transmitting radio waves, but I came to find out that iPhones do not have the ability to receive radio waves built in.

Then I considered bluetooth, but I found out that we can only transmit one bluetooth signal at a time.

Could I do it by hooking up my Pi to my network via an ethernet chord then transmitting it over the local network?

In short, is there a way to send music from my Pi to iPhones without changing each iPhone's system settings (much) that has an advantage over hosting from my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You could always look into setting up an Icecast server on the pi. Using a USB WiFi card connected to the pi as an access point. Then just have everyone download an Icecast client app to their device.  I've never setup an Icecast server myself.

Another option would be to setup a web server running on the pi once again with a WiFi adapter acting as an access point. Then just setup a simple webpage that streams music and have everyone visits the site on their phone. This has the added benefit of not having to download any apps on the phones themselves.

Once again I've never personally set this up before myself, but it seems like a viable option. Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, Icecast runs a server that streams to an app client via wifi, correct? In that case is there any advantage to use the Pi over just my PC to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Logitech Media Server** (Squeeze Server) to stream other devices at my home. I installed Logitech Media Server on Raspberry Pi, squeezeplay clients to other devices (iPad, Android phone, laptop which runs ubuntu) i have.

If your devices in same network, Squeezeplay automatically looks up the server then connect. You can select which device will play which source (local mp3, radio broadcast, etc.) from media server's web interface. Also you can control media server remotely with ios, android applications.

Download and install media server onto RPi.

```
wget http://downloads.slimdevices.com/LogitechMediaServer_v7.7.2/logitechmediaserver_7.7.2_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i logitechmediaserver_7.7.2_all.deb
sudo service logitechmediaserver start
```

After starting service, check your server is running at default port http://your_pi.ipaddress:9000

You can set up media server from web interface.

Then, install client application. You can find packages list at  https://code.google.com/p/squeezeslave/downloads/list

Install application, then run squeezeslave, it will find your server. You can find more information about squeezeslave at http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/SqueezeSlave

Comment: Is there any advantage to use my Pi to host a Squeeze Server as opposed to my PC?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I am using Pi headless, without speakers. Also my Pi and of course Squeeze server works 7/24 online.